# android contacts manager

Tags: android, contacts

I want to emulate the native contact manager behaviour in android, how can I do this? Is there an example or some code? I know how to retrieve the contacts and display them, what I need to be able to do is click on a contact name, which take me to the contact's details.

The part I'm stuck at is how to perform actions with the contact's details, i.e call a number or email an email address.

Comment: also, you can probably look at the source code for the original contact manager by downloading the source at http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: i have downloaded it but i can't build just the contacts app, i have to build the entire firmware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can retrieve the contacts, make your own activity which displays all the details. Then you can send an e-mail using e-mail composer like this:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "yourid@gmail.com"});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Contact Us");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text field here);

email.setType("message/rfc822");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

And call using this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Similarly, you can send SMS too.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
For `ListView` try this code to implement `onClickListener`:

```
ListView lv;
String listview_array[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN" };

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
   {
       AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListviewOnclickExample.this);
       adb.setTitle("ListView OnClick");
       adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = " + lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
       adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
       adb.show();                     
   }
});
```

Whenever an item from your `ListView` will be selected, you can access it using the `position` variable.

Comment: hi there, the problem is i have a list in a list to display multiple details, and i am not able to implement an onClick listener

Comment: To display multiple details for e.g. phone numbers, you can implement using `ListView` and define `onClickListener` for this `ListView`. Then whenever an item is selected, you can access that item using its index number.

Comment: at the minute, I have iterated through the contact's details and populated a list (i.e listOfNumbers, listOfEmailIds) I have then passed that list to an adapter to display. How can I implement the onClickListener here?